# return records with first value from column partitioned by other columns

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby, window-functions

I have a dataframe with values like the input data below.  For some records I have the same values of "name" and "type" but a different value for "id".  I'd like to create a new dataframe like the output data I have below, where I only have the first "id" value for the same "name" and "type" values.  In sql I might use a window function to pull off something like this.  Is there a slick way to do it with pandas?

input data:

```
name type id
bob  hat  1
sara cat  1
bob  hat  c
```

output data:

```
name type id
bob  hat  1
sara cat  1
```

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(subset=["name","type"],keep="first")`?

Comment: @HenryYik Thank you, that worked perfect.